# How to access viewModel that is created inside compose navigation destination in instrumented test

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

If I create viewModel outside NavHost component then I can access this viewModel in my instrumented tests.
For example:

```
@Composable
fun Navigation(myViewModel: MyViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {
    NavHost(...) {
        composable("example1") {
            ...
        }
    } 
}
```

And view model e.g.:

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {
    ...
}
```

I can access this viewModel in Instrumented test like this:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@HiltAndroidTest
class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
    @get:Rule(order = 0)
    val hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @get:Rule(order = 1)
    val composeRule = createAndroidComposeRule<MainActivity>()

    @Test
    fun exampleTest() {
        // accessing view model
        val myViewModel = composeRule.activity.viewModels<MyViewModel>().value
        ...
    }
}
```

But how can I access viewModel in my instrumented tests when it's created inside NavHost?

```
@Composable
fun Navigation() {
    NavHost(...) {
        composable("example2") {
            Example2Screen()
        }
    } 
}
@Composable
fun Example2Screen(myViewModel: MyViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to access the viewmodel at that point?

Comment: For example lets say Example2Screen has list where we can add/remove elements and this list is stored in viewModel. It would be good if in test I can verify that list size in viewModel is as expected after removing/adding element in ui.

Comment: I believe this is what a unit test is intended for. Assuming your list is a state which is being displayed using. a `LazyColumn`,  you can use the compose rule to check the size of the children in the LazyColumn and this should be equal to your list, because the UI is driven by state. This is if you still want to perform a UI test

Comment: Okay in this example compose rule to check the size of LazyColumn makes sense. But other example that I can think of when I would like to access viewModel in my test is: When I store something into db, and I would like to verify that it is actually stored into db. The easiest way to test it for me seems to add @TestOnly method in viewModel and call it in my test. So what would be the other option in this case, in unit tests db is mocked and I can't use unit tests for this.

Comment: I'm assuming you are not the database provider. If you are using a database like Room or SQLite etc, it falls on the developers of that database to test the use cases you are mentioning. If you call an insert method on Room, you should be 100% sure that the data will be saved. This behaviour has already been tested by Google, you don't have to test Google's code for them. What you should be testing instead is what happens to your app after a data is saved, this is how you test your code's behaviour and not it's implementation.

Comment: I'm not the database provider, but it would still say it would be good have end-to-end tests for application to verify as expected. And for select queries many times we might write custom queries and it still would be good verify that it works correctly. So I am kind of disagree that if I am not db provider I can ignore db while writing tests.